# Many-to-many relation Laravel Eloquent. Fetch related table with specific related id

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am writing a query in Laravel 8 using Eloquent. There is a many-to-many relation between subjects and streams and their pivot table is courses.

subjects:
id
name

streams
id
name

courses
id
subject_id
stream_id

I have to fetch subjects with specific stream.

I have written the following query.

$this->subjects = Subject::has('streams',$this->stream)->get();

I am having problem in this.

courses table :

| id | stream_id | subject_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |

This is the sample data. If I want to fetch subject where stream id is 1 then it is only fetching subject with ids 3 and 4 and not fetching subjects with id 1 and 2. Can anyone explain me why it is skipping subject ids with 1 and 2 ?

PLease anyone can help me with this.
Thank you in advance . :)

Edited

```
class Subject
{
   public function streams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stream::class, 'courses', 
'subject_id', 'stream_id');
    }
}


class Stream
{
   public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'courses', 
'stream_id', 'subject_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `$this->stream` ? An object? An array of ids?

Comment: It's just a single id

Comment: @KratikaAgrawal Heyy, FIrstly you should add your relation methods in your question. Because without showing relationship it's hard to give any answer.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Thanks. I have added the block of code for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the table name where you are referencing the id to avoid ambiguity.

```
$this->subjects = Subject::whereHas('streams', function($query) use ($stream){
    $query->where('stream.id', $stream->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: It didn't work. Throwing error  " unknown column stream.id"

Comment: @KratikaAgrawal Yes, Your table name `streams` that's why unknown. Please use `streams.id`

Answer (score 1):

For fetching models having a specific related model you can use `whereHas()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Assuming that `$this->stream` is a `Stream` model, you can use a closure for `whereHas` method:

```
$stream = $this->stream;

$this->subjects = Subject::whereHas('streams', function($query) use ($stream){
   $query->where('streams.id', $stream->id);
})->get();
```

Edit: since $this->stream is an `id` you should do

```
$stream = $this->stream;

$this->subjects = Subject::whereHas('streams', function($query) use ($stream){
   $query->where('streams.id', $stream);
})->get();
```

Comment: I tried with whereHas() as well but it's not working. It's throwing error "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous"

Comment: I've updated my answer, just specify the `streams` table in `where()` condition